# Why is my setState in a setTimeout in a useEffect not updating my state?

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, timeout, use-effect, use-state

I have a react component, where I want to store the width of a div in a state. I am using the following code (extracted from my project):

```
const Test = (): JSX.Element => {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    const [width, setWidth] = useState(123);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            const width = ref.current?.clientWidth || 321;
            setWidth(() => width);
        }, 1000);
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.error(width);
        }, 2000);
    }, []);

    ...

    return (
        <div ref={ref}>Test</div>
    );
}
```

When running it, in the console I see the value `123` printed (original value of width) and not the actual width or `321`.

I am sure I am doing something silly, but I have been staring at this code for already quite some time. So, I hope someone can help!

(the reason I am using a `setTimeout` is that I have read somewhere, that sometimes you don't get the right value if you get `ref.current.clientWidth` right away.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your approach.

It is generally best to avoid using `setTimeout` to wait on dynamic changes like component rendering. At best, it makes your application extra slow by adding unnecessary waiting times; and it's possible that whatever you are waiting on will still not be ready at the end of the timeOut, which is a source of bugs.

In this case, you don't actually want to wait 1s; you want to wait until that `div` is rendered, and your code should reflect that instead.

[This link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node) details the solution to your problem as recommended by React, including why `useCallback` is actually a better choice than `useRef` in this case. Applied to your example, it should look like this:

```
const Test = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);

  const ref = useCallback(node => {
    if (node !== null) {
      setWidth(node.getBoundingClientRect().width);
    }
  }, []);

    ...

    return (
        <div ref={ref}>Test</div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi @Pierre Lejay: Thank you for your response. Really helpful. There is one remaining problem: the width that is set is incorrect. In my case it is set to 1488 (when I log it to the console), whereas it should be 1404! Any idea why?